# Error on certain loop through of code

Tags: java, casting, compiler-errors, rpn

I have designed a RPN algorithm to compute the result of a sum given to a calculator. My code for the RPN is as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RPNCalculator {
    String operator;
    double number_1;
    double number_2;
    double result;
    public int length_change;

public void calculateResult(ArrayList<Object> outputQueueArray)
{
    int length = outputQueueArray.size();
    length_change = length;
    int i;
    int b;
    int a;
    for(b = 0; b < length; b++){
        for(i = 0; i < length_change; i++){
            if(outputQueueArray.get(i).equals("+") || outputQueueArray.get(i).equals("-") || outputQueueArray.get(i).equals("/") || outputQueueArray.get(i).equals("*")){
                a = i - 2;
                operator = (String) outputQueueArray.remove(i) ;
                number_1 = (double) outputQueueArray.remove(i - 1);
                number_2 = (double) outputQueueArray.remove(i - 2);
                outputQueueArray.add(a,useOperator(number_1, number_2, operator));
                length_change = outputQueueArray.size();
                System.out.println(outputQueueArray);
            }
        }
    }
}

public double useOperator(double number_1, double number_2, String operator)
{
    if(operator.equals("+")){
        return number_2 + number_1;
    }
    else if(operator.equals("-")){
        return number_2 - number_1;
    }
    else if(operator.equals("/")){
        return number_2 / number_1;
    }
    else if(operator.equals("*")){
        return number_2 * number_1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
}
```

if i give the code the following calculation to do:

```
[3.0, 2.0, /, 8.0, 3.0, +, -, 2.0, /]
```

it gives the following output:

```
[1.5, 8.0, 3.0, +, -, 2.0, /]
[1.5, 11.0, -, 2.0, /] java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

So the error occurs when processing [1.5, 11.0, -, 2.0, /]

However if i initially give it the following calculation to do:

```
[1.5, 11.0, -, 2.0, /]
```

It gives the correct answer:

```
[1.5, 11.0, -, 2.0, /]
[-9.5, 2.0, /]
[-4.75]
```

Could anyone help with this :)

p.s. sorry for the long question

Comment: Well, obviously `outputQueueArray` contains both `String` and `Double` and you are blindly casting. It is recommended not to use `List<Object>` for exactly that reason.

Comment: use `instanceof` to check whether the type is `Double` or `String` and then type-cast accordingly.

Comment: @AmanArora generally speaking any use of `instanceof` is code smell. In this case there should be some `Element` interface than is implemented by `Operator` and `Operand`. `Element` should be methods to deduce what the type is. This is an OO language after all...

Comment: You should post that as an answer so I can upvote it properly :)

Answer (score 3):

You better use a stack.

```
// returns result instead of modifying the input list
// input is still a list of Double s (literals) and String s (operators)
public double calculateResult(ArrayList<Object> input)
{
    // create new java.util.Stack
    // the new stack is empty
    Stack<Double> operands = new Stack<>();
    
    for (Object o : input) {
        if (o instanceof String) {
            // remove operands of the operation from the stack and "replace"
            // with the result of the operation
            double operand2 = operands.pop();
            double operand1 = operands.pop();
            operands.push(useOperator(operand2, operand1, o));
        } else {
            // push a "literal" (i.e. a Double from input) to operands
            operands.push((Double)o);
        }
    }
    if (operands.size() != 1)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input not valid. Missing operator or empty input.");
    return operands.pop();
}
```

This way the algorithm should be significantly faster, since removing elements from position i of an ArrayList L requires O(L.size() - i) time.

#### Example execution for

```
input = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(new Object[] {
new Double(3.0),
new Double(2.0),
"/",
new Double(8.0),
new Double(3.0),
"+",
"-",
new Double(2.0),
"/"}))
```

:

- before loop: `operands = []`
- after iteration with `o = 3.0`: `operands = [3.0]`
- after iteration with `o = 2.0`: `operands = [3.0, 2.0]`
- iteration for `o = "/"`:

  - remove operands from `operands`: `operands = []; operand1 = 3.0; operand2 = 2.0`
  - push result of `(operand1 / operand2)` to stack: `operands = [1.5]`
- after iteration with `o = 8.0`: `operands = [1.5, 8.0]`
- after iteration with `o = 3.0`: `operands = [1.5, 8.0, 3.0]`
- iteration for `o = "+"`:

  - remove operands from `operands`: `operands = [1.5]; operand1 = 8.0; operand2 = 3.0`
  - push result of `(operand1 + operand2)` to stack: `operands = [1.5, 11.0]`
- iteration for `o = "-"`:

  - remove operands from `operands`: `operands = []; operand1 = 1.5; operand2 = 11.0`
  - push result of `(operand1 - operand2)` to stack: `operands = [-9.5]`
- after iteration with `o = 2.0`: `operands = [-9.5, 2.0]`
- iteration for `o = "+"`:

  - remove operands from `operands`: `operands = []; operand1 = -9.5; operand2 = 2.0`
  - push result of `(operand1 + operand2)` to stack: `operands = [-7.5]`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, in you're code what does the variable "stack" refer to?

Comment: @user3120023: Sorry, should be `operands`.

Comment: Sorry just to clarify, operands is an empty stack and input is my list of tokens, so why does operands get pop(). Do i assign the value of the ArrayList input to the new stack operands? Thanks again :)

Comment: One quick point is that `Stack` extends `Vector` and as such as `synchronized` and best avoided - you are better off using a `Queue` such as a `LinkedList`.